# Choosing the text of a li by having his number

Tags: jquery

I try to have the text of all li element one after one by using their number and then selecting only the number to have the total price. But i can't have the text and i can't figure out why!

```
function add_basket(that) {
    var w=$(that).text();

       $(".basket").append("<li>"+w+"</li>");

       var lis = $("#basket-cleaner li");
       var j;
       for (j=0; j<lis.length; j++) {
           var ind=j+2;
          var str=$("#basket-cleaner li:nth-child(ind)").text();

       }
    }


 <div onClick="add_basket(this);" class="menu-item tops"> <p>Hung Shirt 2.5$</p></div>



    <ul class="basket" id="basket-cleaner">
      </ul>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

you are not using the `ind` variable correctly, in your selector code it's just a string, do as follows:

```
$("#basket-cleaner li:nth-child(" + ind +")").text();
```